# Allure @Step(String s, byte[] b) when b is large (2.12.1 allure)

Tags: java, allure

Allure 2.12.1
Have out of memory troubles on processing allure @Step 
for large array byte[]

```
@Step
public void test(String s, byte[] b){}
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3332)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:124)
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:674)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:208)
at java.util.Arrays.toString(Arrays.java:4446)
at io.qameta.allure.util.ObjectUtils.toString(ObjectUtils.java:70)
at io.qameta.allure.util.ResultsUtils.createParameter(ResultsUtils.java:110)
at io.qameta.allure.util.AspectUtils.lambda$getParameters$2(AspectUtils.java:63)
at io.qameta.allure.util.AspectUtils$$Lambda$488/432285879.apply(Unknown Source)
at java.util.stream.IntPipeline$4$1.accept(IntPipeline.java:250)
at java.util.stream.Streams$RangeIntSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:110)
at java.util.Spliterator$OfInt.forEachRemaining(Spliterator.java:693)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
at io.qameta.allure.util.AspectUtils.getParameters(AspectUtils.java:64)
at io.qameta.allure.aspects.StepsAspects.stepStart(StepsAspects.java:72)
```

is there a way to avoid reporting all method parameters ?

Answer (score 0):

Found answer on allure gitter. Using

```
Allure.step("stepName", (step) -> {})
```

allure-framework/allure-java#282